# Не находит pip в актуальной версии анаконды

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, pip, anaconda

Хочу установить пакет для питона в рамках Анаконды 5.1.0 под Windows 10.

В командной строке прописал pip install xgboost и получил ошибку, команда "pip" либо неправильно написана либо не найдена.

Примечательно, что на другом компьютере с Windows 10 и так же установленной анакондой таких проблем не было

Comment: Попробуй не `pip...` а `pip3...`, в 10 версии с `pip`-ом есть определенные проблемы.

Comment: Тоже не выходит. Та же ошибка

Comment: попробуйте установить `pip`: `conda install pip`

Comment: Он даже не знает команды conda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае была проблема с корпоративной сетью. Для того, чтобы скачался PiP пришлось отключать кабель и подключать гостевую беспроводную сеть на работе. 
Тогда можно запустить программный код сохраненный в формате .py взятый с 
https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py